# Sending vector tile PBF content as response from HTTP Azure function

Tags: postgis, postgresql, c#, vector-tiles, pbf

I wrote Azure function (based on HTTP trigger) and need to return vector tile PBF as response.

I used following piece of C# code to send response from Azure function

```
return new FileContentResult(byteArray, "application/vnd.mapbox-vector-tile");
```

but it is throwing error **{unimplemented type:3}** when we plot the Azure function response on front end map (i.e., Azure Maps),

[image]

**Note :** I tried different headers (application/x-protobuf,image/pbf) and other recommendations given in the similar posts but didn't help me to resolve the issue.

I'm using PostGIS extension methods to generate vector tiles and refer the below query for more information

```
    WITH  bounds AS 
(  SELECT ST_Segmentize(ST_MakeEnvelope(-5009377.085697301, 5009377.085697301, 0.0, 10018754.1713946, 3857),1252344.2714243252) AS geom, 
    ST_Segmentize(ST_MakeEnvelope(-5009377.085697301, 5009377.085697301, 0.0, 10018754.1713946, 3857),1252344.2714243252)::box2d AS b2d ), 
    mvtgeom AS 
        (     SELECT ST_AsMVTGeom(ST_Transform(t."Wgs84Geometry", 3857), bounds.b2d) AS geom, "RoadName"  
              FROM "Links" t, bounds 
              WHERE ST_Intersects(ST_Transform(t."Wgs84Geometry", 3857), ST_Transform(bounds.geom, 3857)))  
              SELECT ST_AsMVT(mvtgeom.*) FROM mvtgeom
```

How can I send vector tile PBF as an HTTP Azure function response?